# Oracle Database XE : [FATAL] [DBT-50000] Unable to check available system memory

Tags: oracle

I installed oracle database xe on centos 'linux'
and when I run this command: /etc/init.d/oracle-xe-21c configure
I get the following exception:

[FATAL] [DBT-50000] Unable to check available system memory.
CAUSE: An exception occured while checking kernel parameter.
*ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:*
Exception details

- PRVG-1901 : failed to setup CVU remote execution framework directory "/tmp/CVU_21.0.0.0.0_oracle/" on nodes "server1" Please select a different work area for the framework PRVH-0185 : Path "/tmp/CVU_21.0.0.0.0_oracle/" does not allow execution on node "server1". Cannot run program "/tmp/CVU_21.0.0.0.0_oracle/exectask.sh": error=13, Permission denied PRVH-0516 : failed to retrieve CVU remote execution framework version from node "server1" during an attempt to setup remote execution framework directory "/tmp/CVU_21.0.0.0.0_oracle/" server1 : /bin/sh: /tmp/CVU_21.0.0.0.0_oracle//exectask.sh: Permission denied server1 : /bin/sh: /tmp/CVU_21.0.0.0.0_oracle//exectask.sh: Permission denied

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what happens when `/tmp` is mounted with the `noexec` option. Remount it without the `noexec` option. Or you can try redirecting the temp files using the `TMPDIR` environment variable.

Comment: Thank you so much. this solved the problem.